# Retain the values in the drop-down box even after reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a display.html where I have a drop-down menu:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label " for="company">Choose the required data</label>
<div>
<select id="selectSensor" class="form-control">
<option selected>Select sensor type</option>
</select>
<select id="selectTime" class="form-control">
<option selected>Select timestamp</option>
</select>
</div>

</div>
```

I have a function which fetches its value:

```
function checkEntry() {
console.log("hello");
    typeSelected = $("#selectSensor").val();
    timeSelected = $("#selectTime").val();
    if (timeSelected != "" && (typeSelected != ""))
        idValue = 4;
}
```

When the page gets reloaded, the values disappear. How can I retain the values even after it is refreshed?

Comment: You can use cookies or session storage...

Comment: Session, Cookies or localStorage

Answer (score 2):

You want to use some type of Store for this, either localStorage or sessionStorage. In your case its probably best to use sessionStorage, while this type of storage is used for storage in a single session.

HTML:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Store
sessionStorage.setItem("selectTime", "value");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("selectTime");
```

---

Example with localStorage:

https://jsfiddle.net/xdtbyg2t/16/

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a database for further work, cookie will work but not over time.